# ElasticSearch filter to match a single date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I've been working with elastic search for sometime now and I've hit a roadblock where I have to search for events that match a particular start date (start_at). I've indexed my fields as

```
mapping do
    indexes :name,    :type => 'string', :analyzer => 'snowball'
    indexes :description, :type => 'string', :analyzer => 'snowball'
    indexes :start_at, :type => 'date'
    indexes :end_at, :type => 'date'
    indexes :tag_list, :type => 'string', :analyzer => 'snowball'
    indexes :lat_lon, :type => 'geo_point'
    indexes :user_details, :type => 'string'    
  end



  def to_indexed_json
    to_hash.merge({
      :user_details => (user ? user.to_index : nil),
      :artist_details => (artists ? artists.each{|artist| artist.to_index }: nil),
      :primary_genre => (genre ? genre.name : nil),
      :lat_lon => [lat, lng].join(',')
    }).to_json
  end
```

So when i hit

```
 Tire.search('events') do 
    # ignore search query keywords
    filter range: {start_at: {gte: Date.today, lt: Date.tomorrow}}
 end
```

Returns nothing but works great with single ranges. That is

```
 Tire.search('events') do 
    # ignore search query keywords
    filter range: {start_at: {gte: Date.today}}
 end
```

I indexed Elasticsearch for events mappings to make start_at and end_at into dates or it would perform term matches on those but something like this would not be the answer

```
Tire.search('events') do
  query do
    string "start_at: #{Date.today}"
 end
end
```

Since this performs a string match it results in all records because the tokenizer would break into 2012, 05, 16 and since 2012 and 16 may match in multiple areas so it would return all matches.

I know I'm missing something very basic. I would appreciate any help on this.

**Update**

```
Event.find_all_by_start_at(Date.tomorrow + 1.day).size
  Event Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`start_at` = '2012-05-19'
 => 1
```

So I have events for that day. Now when I run it with elastic search

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :024 > Tire.search('events') do
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :025 >     filter :range, :start_at => {gte: Date.tomorrow + 1.days, lt: Date.tomorrow + 2.days}
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :026?>   end

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :029 > x.to_curl
 => "curl -X GET \"http://localhost:9200/events/_search?pretty=true\" -d '{\"filter\":{\"range\":{\"start_at\":{\"gte\":\"2012-05-19\",\"lt\":\"2012-05-20\"}}}}'"
```

```
{"events":{"event":{"properties":{"allow_comments":{"type":"boolean"},"artist_details":{"type":"string"},"artist_id":{"type":"long"},"city":{"type":"string"},"comments_count":{"type":"long"},"confirm":{"type":"boolean"},"created_at":{"type":"date","format":"dateOptionalTime"},"description":{"type":"string","analyzer":"snowball"},"end_at":{"type":"string"},"event_attendees_count":{"type":"long"},"event_content_type":{"type":"string"},"event_file_name":{"type":"string"},"event_file_size":{"type":"long"},"genre_id":{"type":"long"},"hits":{"type":"long"},"id":{"type":"long"},"interview":{"type":"boolean"},"lat":{"type":"double"},"lat_lon":{"type":"geo_point"},"lng":{"type":"double"},"location":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string","analyzer":"snowball"},"online_tix":{"type":"boolean"},"primary_genre":{"type":"string"},"private":{"type":"boolean"},"start_at":{"type":"string"},"state":{"type":"string"},"tag_list":{"type":"string","analyzer":"snowball"},"updated_at":{"type":"date","format":"dateOptionalTime"},"user_details":{"type":"string"},"user_id":{"type":"long"},"venue_id":{"type":"long"},"zip":{"type":"string"}}}}}
```

Comment: I am not sure but you can try boolean must as you have to match the whole date.

Comment: Could you verify that the start_at field is really indexed as Date by running curl localhost:9200/events/_mapping ?

Comment: @imotov I've posted an update on that with the to_curl on the request.

Comment: @Cage i tried it with boolean queries too and I get the same result :(

Comment: @Sid, your query looks right, but I was asking about mapping. Could you run curl localhost:9200/events/_mapping and post result?

Comment: @imotov you are right its mapped as string. But the mapping i've in the code suggests  it be mapped as date.

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch tries to be flexible in handing mappings. At the same time, it has to deal with limitations of underlying search engine - Lucene. As a result, when existing mapping contradicts the updated mapping, the new mapping is ignored. Another feature of elasticsearch that probably played a role in this issue is automatic mapping creation based on the data. So, if you

1. Created new index
2. Indexed a records with the field start_at with a string that contains a date in a format that elasticsearch didn't recognize
3. Updated mapping assigning type "date" to the start_at field

you ended up with the mapping where the field start_at has type "string". The only way around it is to delete the index and specify the mapping before adding the first record.

Comment: Thanks @imotov for all the answers and comments. So when I do tire:import FORCE=true doesn't that delete the index and reindex the whole thing. Shouldn't it get fixed then? My start_at fields were mapped as string initially but I reindexed the entire model. Doesn't that take care of it?

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem you need to use a search query - but a filter. Try something like this:

```
filter(:range, date: {
            to: params[:date],
            from: params[:date]
        }) if params[:date].present?
```

Where `params[:date]` should match the format:

```
>> Time.now.strftime('%F')
=> "2014-03-10"
```

and could be anything - both hardtyped or passed in as parameters.

Fields `:start_at` and `:end_at` should be mapped as `:type => 'date'` (just as you have now), no need to change to string or anything alike.

This approach works with mapping of a field of `date`, should be fine also for `datetime` as  Tire/Elasticsearch doesn't seem to differ those two field types.

Bonus: you can find nice rails elasticsearch/tire production setup example here:
https://gist.github.com/psyxoz/4326881